# assembly printing float

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86

I'm having some troubles with the following actions in assembly.
I'm working on assembly IA32. Assume -4(%ebp)=x and -8(%ebp)=y and I get them from user already.
this is the code:

```
format1:    .string "Multiply : %u * %u = %llu\n"
format2:    .string "Divide : %u / %u = %u\n"

# operation multiply
movl    -4(%ebp),   %eax
mull    -8(%ebp)
pushl   %edx
pushl   %eax
pushl   -8(%ebp)
pushl   -4(%ebp)
pushl   $format1
call    printf

# operation divide
movl    -4(%ebp),    %eax   
divl    -8(%ebp)
pushl    %eax
pushl   -8(%ebp)
pushl   -4(%ebp)
pushl   $format2
    call    printf
```

The reason the result of the multiply is in %llu is because I want to be able to multiply 2 long numbers and print the result even if it reaches 64 bytes.
And also that in %edx the mull command saves the "other 32 bytes" of the 64 byte result, so I need to push it to the stack as well for the printf.
e.g. I want this output:

```
 Multiply : 4000000000 * 2 = 16000000000
```

Also, I want the divide operation of 3 with 4 to return X.YZ result. (no more than 2 numbers in the mantissa, and no rounding off)
e.g.

```
Divide : 3 / 4 = 0.75
```

for 19 and 1000:

```
Divide : 19 / 1000 = 0.01
```

and for 8 and 2:

```
Divide : 8 / 2 = 4.00
```

I really tried alot to get the result but no success.
thanks ALOT! :)

Comment: Float? You need to use floating point instruction rather than idiv which only does integer division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can use `scanf`, just pass the correct arguments.
As you have been told, for floating point result you need to use some floating point divide and a floating point format for printing.

Note that according to calling convention, you should preserve value of `ebx` register. Furthermore, you should keep stack balanced, and preferably aligned.

A possible solution:

```
.comm x,4,4
.comm y,4,4

.section    .rodata

format1:    .string "Div : %d / %d = %g\n"
format2:    .string "Mod : %d %% %d = %d\n"
format3:    .string "%d %d"

.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
main:
    subl $32, %esp # allocate space, preserve alignment

    movl $format3, (%esp)
    movl $x, 4(%esp)
    movl $y, 8(%esp)
    call scanf

# operation divide
    fildl x
    fidivl y
    fstpl 12(%esp) # x / y

    movl $format1, (%esp)
    movl x, %eax
    movl %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl y, %eax
    movl %eax, 8(%esp)
    call printf

# operation modulo
    movl x, %eax
    cltd
    idivl y
    movl $format2, (%esp)
    movl x, %eax
    movl %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl y, %eax
    movl %eax, 8(%esp)
    movl %edx, 12(%esp)
    call printf

    addl $32, %esp
    xor %eax, %eax
    ret
```

See the [code in operation](http://ideone.com/JbnTm5).

Comment: Also note that printf always expects double-precision floats!