# assembly multiply operation 64 bits

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86

I'm having some troubles with the following actions in assembly.
I'm working on assembly IA32. Assume -4(%ebp)=x and -8(%ebp)=y and I get them from user already (both 32 bits-longs).
this is the code:

```
format1:    .string "Multiply : %u * %u = %llu\n"
format2:    .string "Divide : %u / %u = %u\n"

# operation multiply
movl    -4(%ebp),   %eax
mull    -8(%ebp)
pushl   %edx
pushl   %eax
pushl   -8(%ebp)
pushl   -4(%ebp)
pushl   $format1
call    printf

# operation divide
movl    -4(%ebp),    %eax   
divl    -8(%ebp)
pushl    %eax
pushl   -8(%ebp)
pushl   -4(%ebp)
pushl   $format2
    call    printf
```

The reason the result of the multiply is in %llu is because I want to be able to multiply 2 long numbers and print the result even if it reaches 64 bytes.
And also that in %edx the mull command saves the "other 32 bytes" of the 64 byte result, so I need to push it to the stack as well for the printf.
e.g. I want this output:

```
 Multiply : 4000000000 * 2 = 16000000000
```

Also, I want the divide operation of 3 with 4 to return X.YZ result. (no more than 2 numbers in the mantissa, and no rounding off)
e.g.

```
Divide : 3 / 4 = 0.75
```

for 19 and 1000:

```
Divide : 19 / 1000 = 0.01
```

and for 8 and 2:

```
Divide : 8 / 2 = 4.00
```

I really tried alot to get the result but no success.
thanks ALOT! :)

Comment: `4000000000 * 2 = 16000000000`? Star Wars: The Pentium Strikes Back?

Comment: Just wanted to give an example, I need to be able to have a result of maximum 64 bits. And I couldn't make this example work in my code yet :/

Comment: Why? Why have you tagged this C or C++? If you insist on C, have you asked your local C expert, namely your C compiler, how he would do such a thing? (e.g with gcc or clang the option -S produces quite nice assembly code)

Comment: For the division, multiply the numerator by 100 (being careful about overflow), then insert a decimal point before the last two digits.

Answer (score 0):

`mull` is for integer multiplication and `divl` is for integer division. For floating point numbers you can use floating point instructions `fmul` and `fdiv`.

An alternative way to do it is as Jerry Coffin suggests in his comment, scale the factors before integer multiplication each eg. by 100 and treat the resulting integer number as 100*100 = 10000 times too big.

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication [should work as-is](http://ideone.com/nBcKkI).
How to divide to get floating point result I have already [answered in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554394/assembly-printing-float/13554927).
If you only need to print them to two digits, you can use the appropriate format string.

**Update**: working code showing truncation to two digits:

```
.comm x,4,4
.comm y,4,4

.section    .rodata

format1:    .string "Div : %d / %d = %.2f\n"
format2:    .string "Mod : %d %% %d = %d\n"
format3:    .string "Multiply : %u * %u = %llu\n"
format4:    .string "%d %d"
const100:   .int 100

.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
main:
    subl $32, %esp # allocate space, preserve alignment

    movl $format4, (%esp)
    movl $x, 4(%esp)
    movl $y, 8(%esp)
    call scanf

# operation divide
    fildl x
    fimul const100
    fidivl y
# truncate to integer
# use this if current FPU rounding mode
# is known to be truncate
#   frndint
# otherwise use this
    fnclex
    fnstcw (%esp)       # save a copy to modify
    fnstcw 2(%esp)      # and a copy to preserve
    orw $0x0c00, (%esp) # rounding mode = truncate
    fldcw (%esp)        # activate
    frndint             # do the truncate
    fldcw 2(%esp)       # restore original
# end of truncate code
    fidiv const100
    fstpl 12(%esp) # x / y

    movl $format1, (%esp)
    movl x, %eax
    movl %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl y, %eax
    movl %eax, 8(%esp)
    call printf

# operation modulo
    movl x, %eax
    cltd
    idivl y
    movl $format2, (%esp)
    movl x, %eax
    movl %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl y, %eax
    movl %eax, 8(%esp)
    movl %edx, 12(%esp)
    call printf

# operation multiply
    movl x, %eax
    mull y
    movl $format3, (%esp)
    movl x, %ecx
    movl %ecx, 4(%esp)
    movl y, %ecx
    movl %ecx, 8(%esp)
    movl %eax, 12(%esp)
    movl %edx, 16(%esp)
    call printf

    addl $32, %esp
    xor %eax, %eax
    ret
```

[See in operation](http://ideone.com/qmsrPO).

Comment: well, the mul doesnt work :S and about the divide, I understood your answer but I need only 2 digits. What appropriate format are you talking about?

Comment: See [your multiplication code here in operation](http://ideone.com/nBcKkI). As for the format string, try `%.2f` to print to two digits.

Comment: the float is rounding the result, try 19 and 1000. instead of giving 0.1 it gives 0.2..

Comment: That's indeed the case. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some useful examples [here](http://x86asm.net/articles/working-with-big-numbers-using-x86-instructions/)

Here is an example how to multiply **two** 32 bit number and output **64** bit result [Linux, GCC]:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *fr = "MUL %u * %u = %llu\n";

int main()
{
        __asm__ (
                        "subl $0x14, %esp\n\t"
                        "movl $10, %eax\n\t"
                        "movl %eax, 0x4(%esp)\n\t"
                        "movl $100, %ebx\n\t"
                        // Multimpy two 32bit values and save 64bit result in edx:eax
                        "mull %ebx\n\t"

                        // Call printf
                        "movl fr, %esi\n\t"
                        "movl %esi, (%esp)\n\t"
                        "movl %ebx, 0x8(%esp)\n\t"
                        "movl %eax, 0xC(%esp)\n\t"
                        "movl %edx, 0x10(%esp)\n\t"
                        "call printf\n\t"
                        "addl $0x14, %esp\n\t");

        return 0;
}

gcc -m32 ./ttt.c; ./a.out
MUL 10 * 100 = 1000
```

For division, you need to convert your data to floating point values and use `fdiv` instruction.

PS. `push` changes `%esp` so you have to do `pop` the same number of times to the restore stack pointer. Otherwise you'll get undefined behavior.